# Delete all Database entries with certain key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have followers in my app. If someone follows someone it creates a new entry for the user that is being followed with a child containing the User ID of the follower.
[image: This is how my structure looks like]

If an User deletes their account I want that all entries of their User ID gets deleted. Is this possible?

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: Aaah sorry. Forgot to add. Java with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete the key, try the following:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
DatabaseReference followRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow");
followRef.child(user.getUid()).removeValue();
```

Get the currently logged in user, and then call `removeValue()` to delete the node.

Comment: Value still remains under "Followers" from another user: https://imgur.com/a/0QZCoVf

Comment: in my code it will get the uid of the currently logged in user, if this uid is not the uid of the logged in user then it wont be deleted

Comment: Problem is If a user follows someone their own uid (current user) gets written under the user that is being followed (other user) as is in the picture. Is there any way to delete that too?

Comment: oh u mean under followers?

Comment: exactly. Sorry if I'm bothering you.

Answer (score 1):

**I assume you want to remove the UID of the `follower` from any possible `followed user`:**

**If that is what you want, then you have to read the `Follow` node, and remove any possible existance of the `follower UID`:**

```
//the user ID

String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

//the main reference node "Follow"

DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow");


//read the node and loop through all UIDs

ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

     //loop through all UIDs under "Follow" and remove the user ID that deleted his/here account from "followers"

     for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

       if(ds.child("followers").child(userID).exists()){

         ds.child("followers").child(userID).getRef().removeValue();

       }
     }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

    }
};
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(listener);
```

Comment: "removeValue" doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

If the user deletes the account then its UID should be deleted from the whole firebase data structure so you can do the following:
If the user which is going to delete its account is logged in then do following:
You can give a Button named **Delete Account** and implement following piece of code on onclicklistener of that Button.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
DatabaseReference followRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(user.getUid()).child("following");
followRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //Getting User id from dataSnapshot
                String userid = data.getValue(String.class);
                DatabaseReference Ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(userid).child("followers").child(user.getUid());
                Ref.removeValue();
             }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Log.i(TAG, "onCancelled: Error: " + databaseError.getMessage());

        }
    });

    DatabaseReference followRef1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(user.getUid());
    followRef1.removeValue();

    DatabaseReference followRef2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user.getUid());
    followRef2.removeValue();
```

If any Query then please let me know
Thank You.

Comment: If you found my answer correct then please upvote it and correct it with the green mark